# How to send BTC to P2WSH address using sats-connect?

Tags: p2wsh

**How can I send BTC to a P2WSH address with sats-connect?**

The sats-connect [documentation](https://docs.xverse.app/sats-connect/methods/sendbtctransaction) provides the following API for sending bitcoin on the testnet. I would like to use this API so I can fund HTLC scripts with Xverse wallet. The documentation example uses a P2SH script address for the recipient, and I would like to use a P2WSH address as my recipient, because my HTLC script uses P2WSH.

```
const sendBtcOptions = {
  payload: {
    network: {
      type: "Testnet",
    },
    recipients: [
      {
        address: '2NBC9AJ9ttmn1anzL2HvvVML8NWzCfeXFq4', //But I want to use a P2WSH address
        amountSats: 1500,
      },
      {
        address: '2NFhRJfbBW8dhswyupAJWSehMz6hN5LjHzR',
        amountSats: 1500,
      },
    ],
    senderAddress: 'paymentAddress',
  },
  onFinish: (response) => {
    alert(response);
  },
  onCancel: () => alert("Canceled"),
};

await sendBtcTransaction(sendBtcOptions);
```

When I try to use this code to send BTC to `tb1qh5a0wdhlck6v3n0s5ncxnpac98wj37xftd3uzkxvhlvfwtpzh9xqh046ll` I get the following error:

```
Error sending BTC with Xverse wallet: Error: Incorrect recipient format
    at sendBtcTransaction
```

So that leads me to the question:

How can I sent BTC to a P2WSH address with sats-connect instead of their recommended P2SH? Is this even possible with sats-connect? If my approach is unreasonable and there is a better way please let me know.